# Access Active Directory data from web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory, windows-authentication

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC3 application with C# and Razor. I set up the authentication mechanism to my application as Windows authentication.

The network uses an **Active Directory** which I use to authenticate the user. Now I would like to create a visit log to trace the (intranet) users that access the application and which operation they perform.

How can I, by using c# code, get from **Active Directory** the username of the users that is currently in my application?

Thanks

Francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside an MVC controller:

```
string username = User.Identity.Name;
```

(provided that the site uses windows authentication)

Comment: (the membership provider will access active directory as needed - you don't need to do that)

Comment: thanks for the answer. In which namespace can I find the User class? For Windows authentication I had just to set up my web config file